# Quickest way to convert 1D byte array to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I've got an array that I can process like this:

```
ba = bytearray(fh.read())[32:]
size = int(math.sqrt(len(ba)))
```

I can tell if a pixel should be black or white given

```
iswhite = (ba[i]&1)==1
```

How can I quickly convert my 1D byte array into a 2D numpy array with row length `size` and white pixels for `(ba[i]&1)==1` and black for others? I create the array like this:

```
im_m = np.zeros((size,size,3),dtype="uint8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# fh containts the file handle

# go to position 32 where the image data starts
fh.seek(32)

# read the binary data into unsigned 8-bit array
ba = np.fromfile(fh, dtype='uint8')

# calculate the side length of the square array and reshape ba accordingly
side = int(np.sqrt(len(ba)))
ba = ba.reshape((side,side))

# toss everything else apart from the last bit of each pixel
ba &= 1

# make a 3-deep array with 255,255,255 or 0,0,0
img = np.dstack([255*ba]*3)
# or
img = ba[:,:,None] * np.array([255,255,255], dtype='uint8')
```

There are several ways to do the last step. Just be careful you get the same data type (`uint8`) if you need it.

Comment: Well I'm having a bit of an issue, here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/qX69JxpZ

I'm trying to export to a jpg, but I get the error "Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels"

Comment: The structure seems to be a single outer array with an array within it of pixel arrays (3 number)

Comment: @Christian Stewart. I had a typo in my code on the row with reshape. I fixed it. The point is that `a.reshape(x,x)` returns reshaped version of `a` (does not reshape it), whereas `a.resize((x,x))` or `a = a.reshape((x,x))` really change the shape of A. Sorry for the bug!