# Preferred ordering and converting a 1D bytearray to a Numpy nd-array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a helper class to transfer data from a Java ND-Array to a Python numpy nd-array. The Java array uses [ND4J](http://nd4j.org/) and I'm able to ascertain shape, stride, and row/column ordering from the ND4J `INDArray`.

Py4j allows me to natively transmit a `bytearray` back from the JVM. However, I'm not too familiar with numpy and I don't quite know whether it has preference for [row or column ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) and how I can provide shape information if I give it a `bytearray` representing a 1D array of data.

The closest question I could find was this: [Quickest way to convert 1D byte array to 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518034/quickest-way-to-convert-1d-byte-array-to-2d-numpy-array)

However, it doesn't tell me much about providing explicit shape information - it only applies to RGB image data.

So my question is, how can I do something like `np.array(bytearray, shape)` and how can I know numpy's preferred ordering so I can prepare the incoming data?

### Edit

Half-answered my question. Looks like numpy does indeed allow for specific ordering via an extra parameter on many of its array creation methods: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html

### Edit 2

Learning more, I need to make sure that the bytearray (converted from byte[]) is the right datatype. It's almost always going to be `double`, so should I pass a `float` type or a `numpy.float64`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is

```
np.array(bytearray).reshape(shape)
```

where the output of `np.array()` is a 1D array, which you then reshape to be in the shape you want it to be. Note that reshaping does not change the order in memory, only how your data is viewed.

When linearly iterating through a default C-style NumPy array, [the last dimension of your array will iterate the fastest](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray), this means

```
a[0,0,0]
a[0,0,1]
```

are next to each other in memory, while

```
a[0,0,0]
a[0,1,0]
```

are not. Knowing this you should be able to figure out the `shape` argument.

Thirdly, `dtype=float` and `dtype=np.float64` are interchangeable, which you can confirm by comparing

```
print np.arange(1, dtype=float).dtype
print np.arange(1, dtype=np.float64).dtype
```